# What is the difference between Get-InstalledModule and Get-Module -ListAvailable?

Tags: powershell

As far as I can tell they do the same, so what is the reason to use one over the other?

(Sorry, SO question rule engine - have no idea what else to say)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, observe:

```
 C:\> (Get-InstalledModule xyz.ps.core).RepositorySourceLocation
http://devstatic.xyz.com/prdnuget/nuget
 C:\> (Get-Module xyz.ps.core -ListAvailable).RepositorySourceLocation.AbsoluteUri
http://devstatic.xyz.com/prdnuget/nuget
file:///C:/Users/mkharitonov/LocalTestPSRepository
```

The module `xyz.ps.core` was installed both times using `Install-Module`. Only once it was installed from a local repository and the other time - from a remote NuGet repository.

In both cases the module is installed into the system location, i.e. it is in `PSModulePath`. What does matter, apparently, is whether it was downloaded from a remote location.

I wish Microsoft documentation explained it and provided a rationale for having this method.

Answer (score 8):

`Get-InstalledModule` is part of `PowerShellGet` and will list installed modules using `Install-Module` cmdlet, But `Get-Module -ListAvailable` shows modules from all locations mentioned in `$env:PsModulePath` location.

Comment: So, if I know my module is installed with `Install-Module`, then `Get-InstalledModule -Name xyz` would be the same as `Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name xyz`? Will the former be faster than the latter?

Answer (score 2):

Get-InstalledModule will list installed modules using Install-Module and which are not naively installed. However Get-Module -ListAvailable shows modules from all locations mentioned in $env:PsModulePath location.

See below Snip for reference :

```
*PS C:\Users\xyz> Get-InstalledModule
 `PS C:\Users\xyz> Get-Module -ListAvailable
Directory: C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules
```

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Script     1.0.1      Microsoft.PowerShell.Operation.V... {Get-OperationValidation, Invoke-OperationValidation}
Binary     1.0.0.1    PackageManagement                   {Find-Package, Get-Package, Get-PackageProvider, Get-Pac...
Script     3.4.0      Pester                              {Describe, Context, It, Should...}
Script     1.0.0.1    PowerShellGet                       {Install-Module, Find-Module, Save-Module, Update-Module...
Script     2.0.0      PSReadline                          {Get-PSReadLineKeyHandler, Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler, Rem...
    Directory: C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Manifest   1.0.0.0    AppBackgroundTask                   {Disable-AppBackgroundTaskDiagnosticLog, Enable-AppBackg...*`

---

However if the module is not installed both will throw same exception.
`PS C:\Users\Asim> $Error.Exception.Message[-1]
Unable to find type [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.PowerShellGet.Telemetry]`
.