# " Get-InstalledModule -name az " Command gives 'No result Found'" But all Az commands works

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I had to check if `Az` or `AzureRM` module is installed on some machines.

But I faced one issue where all `Az` commands work from `PowerShell` but when I execute `Get-InstalledModule -name az` it gives the below error:

> PackageManagement\Get-Package : No match was found for the specified
>   search criteria and module names At C:\Program
>   Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:2216
>   char:9
>   +         PackageManagement\Get-Package @PSBoundParameters | Microsoft. ...
>   +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.Power...lets.GetPackage:GetPackage) [Get-Pac
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.GetPackage

Need to understand why `Get-InstalledModule` command not giving the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Try with other command available in powershell
**Get-Module -ListAvailable** .
This option will display all the installed modules. As you said powershell is working for all the az commands, this option might work for you :)

Comment: At least it gives all the AZ installed modules :) But still can’t figure out why Get-InstalledModule does not work.

Comment: I found difference between Get-Module -ListAvailable and Get-InstalledModule in below article:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56105056/what-is-the-difference-between-get-installedmodule-and-get-module-listavailable                                                                               Get-InstalledModule will list installed modules using Install-Module and which are not naively installed. However Get-Module -ListAvailable shows modules from all locations mentioned in $env:PsModulePath location.

Answer (score 0):

Try call this commands

```
Get-InstalledModule -name "az*"
```

Az have many modules in pack(also AZ have old version that called "Azure" may be you have it),like:

```
Az.Accounts
Az.Advisor
Az.Aks
Az.AnalysisServices
Az.ApiManagement
Az.ApplicationInsights
Az.Automation
Az.Batch
Az.Billing
Az.Cdn
Az.CognitiveServices
Az.Compute
Az.ContainerInstance
Az.ContainerRegistry
Az.DataBoxEdge
Az.DataFactory
Az.DataLakeAnalytics
Az.DataLakeStore
Az.DeploymentManager
Az.DevTestLabs
Az.Dns
Az.EventGrid
Az.EventHub
Az.FrontDoor
Az.HDInsight
Az.HealthcareApis
Az.IotHub
Az.KeyVault
Az.LogicApp
Az.MachineLearning
Az.ManagedServices
Az.MarketplaceOrdering
Az.Media
Az.Monitor
Az.Network
Az.NotificationHubs
Az.OperationalInsights
Az.PolicyInsights
Az.PowerBIEmbedded
Az.PrivateDns
Az.RecoveryServices
Az.RedisCache
Az.Relay
Az.Resources
Az.ServiceBus
Az.ServiceFabric
Az.SignalR
Az.Sql
Az.SqlVirtualMachine
Az.Storage
Az.StorageSync
Az.StreamAnalytics
Az.TrafficManager
Az.Websites
```

Comment: I have already tried (Get-InstalledModule -name "az*") , It gives same error.

Comment: check your powershell module path by `$env:psmodulePath`, standart is  `C:\Users\myuser\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules`. In your error looks like you looking ps module in `At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this same issue, and a workaround that worked for me is to use `Get-InstalledModule` instead.

```
if(Get-InstalledModule -Name Az -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
{
    'Az is installed'
}
else
{
    'Az in NOT installed'
}
```